# How do I select a gallery album/folder when selecting what image to comment?

Tags: facebook

In the Facebook app, if you're going to post a picture, you can select a album from your gallery, like so:
[image: selecting what folder when posting]

But when it comes to the comments, there are no option for it:
[image: comments photo reel]

Facebook Lite allows you select what folder since it opens the Gallery app directly; for some reason the main Facebook ap doesn't have any option for it.

Is there any way to do it or am I stuck with this photo reel in the comments?